# Inner div with margin and padding eventually exceeds outer div when zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div inside of another div. However, because of the margin and padding of the inner div, whenever you zooms in, the inner div exceeds the boundary of the outer div eventually. This doesn't happen if the margin and the padding isn't included. I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so that the inner div never exceeds the outer div, regardless of the margin and padding of the inner div?

```
body {
width: 1000px;
}
#inner {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 90%;
margin: 2%;
padding: 2%;
}
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}

<body>
<div id = 'outer'>
<div id = 'inner'>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does not happen here while zooming.

Comment: I assume when you said here, you mean in jsfiddle? No, it doesn't happen there because the page is pre-coded so that never happens. It happens when you use it in web servers or elsewhere.

Comment: @ManojKumar just tagging you so that you see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `box-sizing: border-box` on your inner div so borders/paddings etc are included in the width.

Actually you should do that to the outer div as well and instead of margins on the inner, set padding on the outer, to ensure everything will be included in the width.

Comment: It takes longer when you include that, but eventually it exceeds it too.

Comment: I tried your code sample with both Chrome and IE/Edge and in neither exceeds the inner div the outer. Have you set doc type etc properly and which browser did you test it with?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` makes the width include the padding but *not* the margin. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values